# Removing all values from a list that satisfy a given condition

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Suppose I have a list,

```
list = Table[{n}, {n, 1, 5}]
(* list = {{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}} *)
```

and I want to remove all values from this list that are greater than 3, so that I get

```
newlist = {{1}, {2}, {3}}
```

Is there a way to do this without having something cumbersome like

```
newlist1 = list /. {4} -> Sequence[]
(* newlist1 = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {5}} *)
newlist = newlist1 /. {5} -> Sequence[]
(* newlist = {{1}, {2}, {3}} *)
```

possibly with an If statement?

Some context: I have a set of circles and a list of each circle's radius, but I want to remove all the circles with radius $r$ outside of a few set ranges. For example, if I have a hundred circles with radii ranging from 1 to 10, I would then like to eliminate all the circles with radii $r<2$, those with $4<r<6$, and those with $r>8$.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Edit: Here's what I've tried by adapting Nasser's code:

```
rad = {34.6302, 10.0623, 6.94622, 26.3059, 52.6308,
       27.1662, ... , 80.0562, 799.3, 44.5997, 14.0357}

DeleteCases[rad, {x_} /; {x>10 And x<700}]
(* the 799.3 is an extreme outlier *)
```

but I apparently don't understand the syntax required for setting multiple constraints. I've tried different variations, like

```
DeleteCases[rad, {x_,y_} /; {x>3, y<1}]
```

but again, no luck.

Comment: `DeleteCases[list, x_ /; First@x > 3]` If you had made your table like this: `Table[n, {n, 1, 5}]` it would be easier a little: `DeleteCases[list, x_ /; x > 3]`

Comment: Nice, that works perfectly for the really simple example I posted. How can I modify it for the circle example? And yeah, I had defined list as I did because `/. 4->Sequence[]` didn't work properly.

Comment: Please include minimal code for your "circles" example.

Comment: In your new code, replace it with this: `DeleteCases[rad, x_ /; (x > 10 && x < 700)]` then it will work. I get `{6.94622, 799.3}`

Comment: If your list has {{a},{b}....} and not {a,b,c}, then use `DeleteCases[rad, x_ /; (First@x > 10 && First@x < 700)]` You need `First@` to be do `x[[1]]` basically, since each `x` is a list now. (you can write `x[[1]]` if you prefer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
rad = {34.6302, 10.0623, 6.94622, 26.3059, 52.6308, 27.1662, 80.0562, 799.3, 44.5997, 14.0357, 1000};

DeleteCases[rad, x_ /; 10 > x || x > 700]

(* {34.6302, 10.0623, 26.3059, 52.6308, 27.1662, 80.0562, 44.5997, 14.0357} *)
```

You need an urgent syntax surgery.  (* lol *)

Or using the converse, `Cases`:

```
Cases[rad, x_ /; 10 <= x <= 700]
```

Comment: Yep, still fairly new to Mathematica. Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my contribution, making the same assumptions as the other two answers:

```
rad = {34.6302, 10.0623, 6.94622, 26.3059, 52.6308, 27.1662, 80.0562, 799.3, 44.5997, 
   14.0357, 1000};

rad ~Pick~ IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{10, 700}], rad]
```

> ```
> {34.6302, 10.0623, 26.3059, 52.6308, 27.1662, 80.0562, 44.5997, 14.0357}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
list = Table[{n}, {n, 1, 5}];

Select[list, #[[1]] <= 3 &]
(*{{1}, {2}, {3}}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
rad = {34.6302, 10.0623, 6.94622, 26.3059, 52.6308, 27.1662, 80.0562, 799.3, 44.5997, 14.0357, 1000};
```

Just for fun (noting would need to vary depending on strictness of inequalities):

```
Clip[rad, {10, 700}, {"out", "out"}] /. ("out" :> Sequence[])
Flatten @ Clip[rad, {10, 700}, {{}, {}}] (* as per Mr. Wizard*)
DeleteCases[Clip[rad, {10, 700}, {"out", "out"}], "out"]
Pick[rad, UnitStep[# - 10] - UnitStep[# - 700] & @ rad, 1] 
(* latter: improvement as per Mr. Wizard , see comment*)
```

all yield:

```
(*{34.6302, 10.0623, 26.3059, 52.6308, 27.1662, 80.0562, 44.5997, \
14.0357}*)
```

Comment: Another one for your `Clip` set: `Flatten @ Clip[rad, {10, 700}, {{}, {}}]`

Comment: I just noticed that you're mapping `UnitStep`.  You're [doing it wrong](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121) (case #4). ;^)  Replace `/@` with `@` for a nice performance improvement.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thank you...I too often forget which functions are listable.